# IIS - Assign a custom count to an application pool : Windows user password "invalid"

Tags: iis, passwords, application-pool, identify

When I want to enter the Windows user's password, IIS tells me that the password is invalid.

However, I am administrator of my machine, and I launched "IIS" in administrator mode.

There must be a trick somewhere ?

Thank you very much for your help !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Getting Error - The specified password is invalid.Type a new password.

A common cause of this error is not adding the domain name to the login (DOMAINNAME\username). It defaults to a local account.

[image]

Or you can do this from the command line using appcmd.exe.

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.userName:DOMAIN\USER_NAME /[name ='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.password:PASSWORD
```

This method is described in the article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771170(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN